# Golang signing a struct using rsa

Tags: go, cryptography, rsa

I have a struct `Transaction` with the following fields,

```
type Transaction struct {
    Sender    string `json:"sender"`
    Receiver  string `json:"receiver"`
    Signature string `json:"signature"`
    Amount    int64  `json:"amount"`
}
```

I also have a function `GetPrivateKey()` which returns a `*rsa.PrivateKey`

```
func GetPrivateKey() (*rsa.PrivateKey, error) {
    key, err := ioutil.ReadFile("/Users/xxx/.ssh/id_rsa")
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    block, _ := pem.Decode(key)
    der, err := x509.ParsePKCS1PrivateKey(block.Bytes)
    if err != nil {
       return nil, err
    }
    return der, err
 }
```

My plan here is to sign the contents of the struct `transaction` using a private key already in the system and then store it as a string in the field `signature` in the struct, For this, I have a function `SignPayload()`

```
func SignPayload(txnObj *Transaction) error {
    privateKey, err := GetPrivateKey()
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    bodyHash, err := rsa.SignPKCS1v15(rand.Reader, privateKey, 
                     crypto.SHA256, []byte(fmt.Sprintf("%v", *txnObj)))
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    txnObj.Signature = string(bodyHash)
    log.Println(txnObj.Signature)
    return err
}
```

Unfortunately, this is not working,`rsa.SignPKCS1v15()` throws an error saying:

> crypto/rsa: input must be hashed message

The end goal here is to use this signature to verify the authenticity of the struct by comparing it with the public key present in the field `sender`.
I'm an absolute newbie in cryptography, What am I doing wrong here? and more importantly, How can I do this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Two things here:

- only small messages can be signed, which is why it's usually a hash. `rsa.SignPKCS1v15` expects a message length matching the hash algorithm's output (256 bits, or 32 bytes for sha-256)
- don't use the `%v` representation of your struct, serialize it instead

The first is [spelled out in the rsa docs](https://golang.org/pkg/crypto/rsa/#SignPKCS1v15). Given a message, you can sign it using the following:

```
message := []byte("message to be signed")
hashed := sha256.Sum256(message)

signature, err := rsa.SignPKCS1v15(rand.Reader, privateKey, crypto.SHA256, hashed[:])
if err != nil {
    panic(err)}
}
```

The second point is more about making your code more robust. You don't want a change in `%v` logic or addition of non-exported fields to cause issues. You may also want to check the signature from a language other than Go.

Thus, you should first marshal your struct. You already have json tags on it, so it's fairly easy:

```
message, err := json.Marshal(txnObj)
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
```

Message is the byte slice passed to `sha256.Sum256` above.

When verifying the signature, you'll need to make sure to zero out the `Signature` field of your struct, marshal it, hash it, and call `rsa.VerifyPKCS1v15`.